# Media file not loading from server in django 3.0

Tags: python, django, media

i have hosted the django project but my media files are not loading so far i have tried to change the location of media url but it is not working and while clicking the path of image ,**page not found**

Settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:    
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
     urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

template

```
 {% for i in slides %}
        <img class="bd-placeholder-img sliding" width="100%" height="100%"
          src="{{i.imag.url}}"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
```

i have tried /media/{{i.imag.url}} but image is not loading
although in local server image was loading in /media/{{i.imag}} in this url but not in server
**while inspecting**  /media/{{i.imag.url}}

```
  <img class="bd-placeholder-img sliding" width="100%" height="100%" src="/media/"  role="img">
```

how to solve it? thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Django is not made to serve media file in production environment. It is better to configure it directly from the web server.

You can use S3 Amazon or Nginx.